How to block the connection between certain nodes on Node-red
I am developing my own Node-Red nodes, and I would like to frame the user, i.e. prevent him from connecting certain nodes together (because they are not compatible) but I cannot do it.
while searching on the internet I found solutions such as flow linter (I just discovered it)
functionGlobalContext: {
    flowLinter: function (flow) {
        let badgeConnected = false;
        let alarmConnected = false;

        flow.forEach(function(node) {
            if (node.type === "Envoyer un mail") {
                node.links.forEach(function(linkId) {
                    const link = flow.links[linkId];
                    const sourceNode = flow.nodes[link.source];
                    if (sourceNode.type === "Passage de badge") {
                        badgeConnected = true;
                    }
                    if (sourceNode.type === "Detection alarme") {
                        alarmConnected = true;
                    }
                });
                
                if (badgeConnected && alarmConnected) {
                    throw new Error("Vous ne pouvez pas connecter à la fois 'Passage de badge' et 'Détection alarme' à un nœud 'Envoyer un mail'.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
},

But after testing, it doesn't work, I also tested using oneditvalidate which didn't work either (I probably misunderstood the use of oneditvalidate)
oneditvalidate: function() {
    const nodeId = this.id;
    let badgeConnected = false;
    let alarmConnected = false;

    RED.nodes.eachLink(function (link) {
        if (link.target && link.target.id === nodeId) {
            const sourceNode = RED.nodes.node(link.source.id);
            if (sourceNode && sourceNode.type === "Passage de badge") {
                badgeConnected = true;
            }
            if (sourceNode && sourceNode.type === "Detection alarme") {
                alarmConnected = true;
            }
        }
    });

    if (badgeConnected && alarmConnected) {
        RED.notify("Vous ne pouvez pas connecter à la fois 'Passage de badge' et 'Detection alarme' à ce nœud.", "error");
        return false; //on empêche le déploiement
    }
    return true;
}

I also have the impression that using:
RED.nodes.eachLink(function (link) {

slows down my node-red a lot when I deploy my node which contains this code.
I can't find much on the internet so I hope someone can help me here, thank you

You don't. Nodes have no knowledge of which other nodes they are connected (and shouldn't)
